# How to grab api before moving on in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, strapi

I am trying to build a super simple react blog using Strapi as my cms. I am running into a problem where it is trying to render the data before it finishes fetching it. I am trying to display the post image, but I get an error about the attributes being undefined right here: `data.data.attributes.image.data.attributes.formats.large.url`.

Here is the ReactJS code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";

function Post() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    const { id } = useParams();

    console.log("handle", id);

    const fetchData = () => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:1337/api/posts/${id}?populate=*`)
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((d) => {
                setData(d);
                // console.log(data);
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    // console.log(data);

    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <img
                src={
                    "http://localhost:1337" +
                    data.data.attributes.image.data.attributes.formats.large.url
                }
                alt="image"
            />
        </>
    );
}

export default Post;
```

Here is the api data retrieved:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "attributes": {
            "postTitle": "First Post",
            "datePosted": "2023-04-25",
            "author": "Caleb",
            "postText": "# Hello <u>**_World_**</u>\nThis is my very first blog post!\n\n![flower-right.png](http://localhost:1337/uploads/flower_right_b36ad9cd80.png)\n\n",
            "createdAt": "2023-04-25T07:20:18.295Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-04-25T08:44:04.003Z",
            "publishedAt": "2023-04-25T07:20:19.972Z",
            "image": {
                "data": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "name": "unsplash_BhfE1IgcsA8-smaller.png",
                        "alternativeText": "header-image",
                        "caption": null,
                        "width": 2560,
                        "height": 1488,
                        "formats": {
                            "thumbnail": {
                                "name": "thumbnail_unsplash_BhfE1IgcsA8-smaller.png",
                                "hash": "thumbnail_unsplash_Bhf_E1_Igcs_A8_smaller_b163301e2d",
                                "ext": ".png",
                                "mime": "image/png",
                                "path": null,
                                "width": 245,
                                "height": 142,
                                "size": 57.28,
                                "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_unsplash_Bhf_E1_Igcs_A8_smaller_b163301e2d.png"
                            },
                            "small": {
                                "name": "small_unsplash_BhfE1IgcsA8-smaller.png",
                                "hash": "small_unsplash_Bhf_E1_Igcs_A8_smaller_b163301e2d",
                                "ext": ".png",
                                "mime": "image/png",
                                "path": null,
                                "width": 500,
                                "height": 291,
                                "size": 222.62,
                                "url": "/uploads/small_unsplash_Bhf_E1_Igcs_A8_smaller_b163301e2d.png"
                            },
                            "medium": {
                                "name": "medium_unsplash_BhfE1IgcsA8-smaller.png",
                                "hash": "medium_unsplash_Bhf_E1_Igcs_A8_smaller_b163301e2d",
                                "ext": ".png",
                                "mime": "image/png",
                                "path": null,
                                "width": 750,
                                "height": 436,
                                "size": 490.23,
                                "url": "/uploads/medium_unsplash_Bhf_E1_Igcs_A8_smaller_b163301e2d.png"
                            },
                            "large": {
                                "name": "large_unsplash_BhfE1IgcsA8-smaller.png",
                                "hash": "large_unsplash_Bhf_E1_Igcs_A8_smaller_b163301e2d",
                                "ext": ".png",
                                "mime": "image/png",
                                "path": null,
                                "width": 1000,
                                "height": 581,
                                "size": 884.48,
                                "url": "/uploads/large_unsplash_Bhf_E1_Igcs_A8_smaller_b163301e2d.png"
                            }
                        },
                        "hash": "unsplash_Bhf_E1_Igcs_A8_smaller_b163301e2d",
                        "ext": ".png",
                        "mime": "image/png",
                        "size": 1276.78,
                        "url": "/uploads/unsplash_Bhf_E1_Igcs_A8_smaller_b163301e2d.png",
                        "previewUrl": null,
                        "provider": "local",
                        "provider_metadata": null,
                        "createdAt": "2023-04-25T06:28:01.746Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2023-04-25T06:35:42.822Z"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "meta": {}
}
```

Comment: `data` is an array, so the usage of `data.data.attributes.image.data.attributes.formats.large.url` doesn't make sense.  Arrays don't have a `data` property.

Comment: You need to check if the data exists before trying to use it. What you want to do if there is data is up to you. Loading text, spinner, whatever. But that’s the easiest way: check if data exists, so different things based on that.

Comment: `data` is actually supposed to be an object, but that still doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is initialized to an empty object:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});
```

Then you try to read a variety of nested properties on that empty object:

```
<img
  src={
    "http://localhost:1337" +
    data.data.attributes.image.data.attributes.formats.large.url
  }
  alt="image"
/>
```

This will clearly fail because `{}` has no property called `data`, so that property is `undefined`, and you can't read the property `attributes` (or any property) on `undefined`.

You can perhaps use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
<img
  src={
    "http://localhost:1337" +
    data.data?.attributes?.image?.data?.attributes?.formats?.large?.url
  }
  alt="image"
/>
```

Though keep in mind that this is likely to show a broken image in the UI.  Alternatively, if you don't want to show the image at all when data isn't available, check if data is available before showing the image:

```
{ data.data ? <img
  src={
    "http://localhost:1337" +
    data.data?.attributes?.image?.data?.attributes?.formats?.large?.url
  }
  alt="image"
/> : null }
```

(You could replace the explicit `null` with a default image, a loading spinner, or nothing at all if you prefer.)

You could slightly simplify the check by initializing to `undefined`:

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
```

And then checking the object itself instead of a property on it:

```
{ data ? <img
  src={
    "http://localhost:1337" +
    data.data?.attributes?.image?.data?.attributes?.formats?.large?.url
  }
  alt="image"
/> : null }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to check if data exists before it shows up, here's an example.

```
return (
   <>
   <Navbar />
 {!data ? ( //if data is currently empty then show the loading (or spinner)
   <p>Loading...</p>
  ) 
  : (
   <img
      src={ "http://localhost:1337" +
            data.data.attributes.image.data.attributes.formats.large.url
           }
          alt="image"
    />
   )
 }
)
```

Comment: I tried that, but it still gave me the same `undefined` error. I added the API data up above.